# Difference between Stream Published Story and Link - Insights reports no clicks on feed post

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-insights

We're using the php sdk to post links in the standard way:

```
$data = array(
    'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
    'link' => $url,
    'type' => 'link'
);

$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $data);
```

Before July 17th they were showing up in insights (Overview -> Sharing) as "Stream Published Stories" and had clicks/comments/likes reported for this period (Traffic -> Stream Publish)

However after July 17th all posts are now showing up as "Links Posted" and have no clicks, comments or likes.. and they definitely get all of those as we are monitoring. Insights does show the impressions but no clicks at all.

Is there a difference between "Stream Published Stories" and "Links Posted"? Anything I should know about why insights wont report clicks? Is this something at the code level, a bug in insights or something facebook changed?